# Regarding linking a c++/cli dll and a c++/cli exe project

Tags: visual-studio, dll, linker, c++-cli, managed

I have a native c++ dll called native.dll.
I have created a c++/cli project called cliWrapper.dll.  In this I have two wrapper classes for some classes in native.dll.

And the compilation for this project works fine.

However, when I try to link cliWrapper.dll with my c++/cli console program, the linker complains that I must compile cliWrapper.dll with the compiler option `/clr:safe`.

Compiling with such option will generate lots of errors since most of native.dll is not verifiable code.

After googling, I see that linking two .module files requires each is compiled with /clr:safe.

Does that mean it is impossible to make a dll that will allow the user to use the wrapper class to do some stuff?  I know I can always put those wrapper classes back into the console project and it will compile without problem but I'm just curious about why Microsoft wants to disable such linking?

Comment: I think you want to "Add Reference" to the cliWrapper instead of linking it.

Comment: That makes little sense.  Ensure that the compiler knows that the DLL contains native code, put #pragma managed(push, off) and #pragma managed(pop) around the #include.  And link the DLL's import library, a .lib file, not the .dll file.